# Building a shopify private or public app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to make a plan to update my client's shopify stores by building Shopify app or using external library. Basically, I want to provide my clients with some convenience by automating the inventory update, order process and extra stuff.

For now, I have only two scenarios.

1. Whenever my wholesale inventory changes, i want to update my client's shopify product list to be updated (quantity, price and product description) accordingly.
2. Whenever my client(shopify store owner) receives an order from his/her customer, i want the order information to be automatically transferred to my server.

If possible, I want my clients to be able to integrate with my application without any tech knowledge. I have looked into the Shopify app (public/private) and some external API(java), because I am a java developer.

I checked Shopify Java library which requires api key and password to be able to access shopify owner's store for product/order access, but I am not sure how user-friendly this approach is in terms of Shopify owner's side.

For Shopify public app, I am not familiar with it, so I am not sure how much I can do with it.

Could somebody provide some details about pros/cons about these approaches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know is that with Shopify, you can connect to their shop using standard HTTPS. Even better, it's all GraphQL now. As for credentials, Shopify is fully modern and offers you two methods of getting credentials.

1. Your merchant client can create credentials with permissions right inside their Shopify Admin -> Apps. They give you the keys, you're in business
2. You get them (or you) to simply click install your App running at some HTTPS address, and you use oAuth to get the credentials.

Either way, makes no difference to the actual code you write to interact with their shop and deal with inventory, sales etc. You do not need to make your App public in the sense of App store, so you can use your partner dashboard to create an App and oAuth install, or like I said, use the private App way.

Comment: Thanks for comment. if I build a shopify app, How does the app talk to my application running in my server?  Can I retrieve my client's api key, shared secret key or store access token?  It seems if I have those, I might be able to access my client's storefront based on my research.

Comment: I dunno... I answered your question above. You can accept my answer and ask your new questions in new questions, or spin your wheels here forever.